# MySQL - Query to return customer's first order

Tags: mysql

Basic schema (only relevant fields shown):

**customers**

```
id  |  fname  |  sname  |  email
```

**orders**

```
order_id  |  customer  |  level  |  timestamp
```

I need to select every customer, but along with their personal details I want to join the `level` of their *first* order.

```
SELECT c.fname, c.sname, c.email, o.level
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer

..?
```

**Edit**

I have tried two solutions so far and they completely kill my entire database. No database requests will complete after running the queries, so I'm wondering if maybe the queries are too large.  There are about 10,000 orders and 15,000 customers. Is this expected? I've never had these problems before on these tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this will work, but is not optimal:

```
SELECT c.fname, c.sname, c.email, o.level
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer
WHERE o.`timestamp` = ( SELECT MIN( o1.`timestamp` ) FROM orders o1 WHERE o1.customer = c.id ) 
GROUP BY c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT c.fname, c.sname, c.email, o.level FROM customers c
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT o1.* FROM orders o1
      JOIN (SELECT customer, MIN(timestamp) timestamp FROM orders GROUP BY customer) o2
        ON o1.customer = o2.customer AND o1.timestamp = o2.timestamp) o
    ON c.id = o.customer;
```

Comment: This query has also killed my database.

Comment: Try on small data set firstly. Do you have indexes on orders.customer, orders.timestamp, customers.id fields? They should increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.fname, c.sname, c.email, o.level
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer
ORDER BY o.timestamp ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This appears to have killed my database, although I'm not sure why. The request has been running for nearly 10 minutes.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` tells that you will get only one results row. Means only one customer, not all customers with one order. Please, see my query below. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes I have seen but unfortunately I ran the query above and both the orders and customers tables appear to have died.  If I try to run any query on the database for those two tables, it loads forever and never completes apparently.  I can stop it if I restart the server to kill the processes but any request on those tables will again kill everything. I need to fix this urgently.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.fname, c.sname, c.email, o.level
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer
ORDER BY o.timestamp
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: This query has also killed my database.

Comment: check names of tables. Is field `customer` in `orders` table integer?

Answer (score 0):

Subselects are definitely not the most efficient but here's a query

```
SELECT c.fname, c.sname, c.email, o.level, 
    (select level from orders 
    where c.id = o.customer order by timestamp asc limit 0,1) as level
FROM customers c
```

This will give you ALL customers (orders or not) and their corresponding level. If you performance is slow, make sure you have proper indexes too